# Blue lines around images within links in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Why do I get a blue line around my images when they're links in IE6?

Is there a quick CSS trick to get rid of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are borders around the image, try adding this to your CSS file:

```
a img { border: 0; }
```

This will remove borders from all images which are hyperlinked.